# Memory used for Float_64

Tags: c, memory

I'm relatively new to using C/C++. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 and am analyzing some code written by someone else. I was notified of an issue where I have a function using too much memory. Virtually all of the pointers in it are Float_64 and I was wondering what kind of repercussions there were if I were to change them to Float_32. How much memory is used by Float_64 and Float_32 and is there any data loss by switching? I apologize if this has already been asked however I couldn't seem to find it.

Thank you!

Comment: The clue is in the names; 64 and 32 are the number of bits used for each type...

Comment: In the comments to my answer, @TZPike05 said this was C, so I changed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Float_64` and `Float_32` are not C++ types defined in the C++ Standard, so they must be something specific to your application or the libraries you are using.

However, if the names are remotely sane, the size of a `Float_64` will be 64 bits (8 Bytes on modern architectures), and a `Float_32` will be 32 bits.  Therefore, if you switch to using `Float_32` instead of `Float_64`, you will reduce the memory pressure of the floats themselves by half.  Now, that's to say nothing of the pointers to the values, which will still be the same size as they were.  So, consider:

```
Float_64 my64;  
Float_32 my32;

Float_64 * my64_ptr = &my64;
Float_32 * my32_ptr = &my32;
```

In the above code, `my64` is half the `sizeof()` as `my32` -- 64 and 32 bits (8 and 4 bytes) respectively.  However, `my64_ptr` and `my32_ptr` are pointers, and pointers are the same size, regardless of what they *point to*.

The reprecussions are another consideration.  A `Float_32` has, presumably, less precision than a `Float_64` -- perhaps half as much, or even less.  If you need floats with a very high degree of signifigance, you may loose precision when converting to the smaller type.  The only way to know for sure is to examine the specifications for both types w.r.t. precesion, and analyze the data you need to manipulate.  However, as a general rule of thumb, the lower precision is very possibly sufficient for most uses.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps explain a lot as well. I didn't realize the pointers were the same size. I'm assuming to free up memory I'll probably want to look at using the free() command for those variables that I'm pointing to.

Comment: I can't give you specific advice without understanding more about your actual program, but I can give you a few general pointers:  1) In C++, never* use `malloc`/`free`.  Use `new`/`delete` instead if you need dynamic allocation, **but** 2) Prefer automatic variables to dynamically allocated variables.  And if you *absolutely must* use dynamic allocation, 3) Use a smart pointer instead of raw pointers. (* There are no "nevers" in programming, but this is pretty damned close.)

Comment: One more pointer:  4) If you do dynamically allocate memory, there must be one `delete` for every `new`.  If you `new` and don't `delete`, you will leak memory.  If you use smart pointers (see #3 above), the `delete` is already written for you in the smart pointer's release mechanism.

Comment: I have a feeling you would cry if you saw this code... malloc is everywhere. I'll see if I can switch it all over to new/delete. Thanks again!

Comment: Good point John. Didn't even think about that. It is in fact in C.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `Float_32` and `Float_64` are not builtin types, so far as I know. That suggests that they're being `typedef`d, probably to `float` (32) and `double` (64).

Assuming that is the case, and probably even if not, your `Float_32` likely takes 32 bits of space and your `Float_64` is 64 bits wide. That's just going from the names. Since you say they're pointers, then the sizes will be platform dependent (32 bits on 32-bit systems and 64 on 64), but still point to the same size values (so the *final* memory use will be pointer+type, or 128 bits on a 64-bit system using a `Float_64`; I'm sure you can do the rest of the math).

By replacing all the `Float_64`s with `Float_32`s, you'll be able to cut the memory use by a quarter to half, but how much that saves depends on how many numbers are in use. In most cases, it's not likely to help, but it very well could if you have millions of floats around.

The possible repercussions are a bit more interesting. Floating point numbers have an annoying property of precision loss, particularly near the edges of their range. For 64-bit floats (doubles), this is well past the trillions. For 32-bit, however, you start to lose precision after the billions, and by the trillions, numbers start skipping quite a bit. Depending on what sort of data you're working with, that may effect you.

Answer (score 0):

> How much memory is used by Float_64 and Float_32

8 bytes (64 bits) and 4 bytes (32 bits) respectively.

> is there any data loss by switching?

Tonnes! `Float_32` is what is known as [single-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (often `float`), while `Float_64` is [double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (normally `double`).

This is actually a bit of a misnomer since doubles have more than double the precision of floats: doubles can represent just under 16 decimal places accurately, while floats can only represent just over 7. That is, you loose 9 decimal places of accuracy by switching, which can easily break some algorithms.